# ansible to compare two strings in a file and check if equals to defined variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Team, I have a kubeconfig file and i need to compare if context name and current-context are same, if yes, I want to proceed further else fail. below is my shell which i want to integrate and run with ansible.

````
cat cluster-user.kubeconfig | yq .contexts[0].name```
"site.test.com"
````

````
cat cluster-user.kubeconfig | yq .[\"current-context\"]```
"site.test.com"
````

```
      - name: "GET API server current-context name with YQ..  "
        shell: "cat cluster-user.kubeconfig | yq .[\"current-context\"]"
        register: string1
        ignore_errors: true

      - debug:
          var: string1.stdout_lines
        when: string1.stdout != ''


      - name: "GET API server contexts name with YQ..  "
        shell: "cat cluster-user.kubeconfig | yq .contexts[0].name"
        register: string2
        ignore_errors: true

      - debug:
          var: string2.stdout_lines
        when: string2.stdout != ''


      - name: "Validate if both string1 and string2 are same, if yes proceed..  "
        failed_when: string2.stdout != string1.stdout
```

output:

````
on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


      - name: "Validate if both string1 and string2 are same, if yes proceed..  "
        ^ here```
anyhint what am i missing?
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
- fail:
     msg: "Validate if both string1 and string2 are same, if yes proceed..."
  when: "'{{ string2.stdout }}' != '{{ string1.stdout }}'"
```

`failed_when`: This is used to fail the particular task when the condition is met. [Failed_When Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure)

`fail`: This is used to fail the progress with a custom message. [Fail Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html)

Comment: got error: 


TASK [GET API server current-context name with YQ..] ******************************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat $HOME/.kube/config/cluster-user.kubeconfig | yq .[\"current-context\"]", "delta": "0:00:00.009022", "end": "2019-09-30 16:12:14.351786", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-09-30 16:12:14.342764", "stderr": "/bin/sh: yq: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: yq: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

Comment: So this resolved your earlier error. Now you have another error saying `yq: command not found`. Wherever you are running this `yq` is not present.

Comment: yq is present. i tested manually on my laptop those shell commands. or is it happening coz i don't have /bin/sh and have /bin/bash?

Comment: can you try to run it with the complete path of `yq`, it seems in ansible it's not running from the path where it should run exactly?

Comment: i see yes that path solved but now its asking for jq. can't i ask ansible to use everything which is used by system default? 

fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat $HOME/.kube/config/cluster-user.kubeconfig | /usr/local/bin/yq .contexts[0].name", "delta": "0:00:00.090166", "end": "2019-09-30 16:17:47.891677", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "yq: Error starting jq: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Is jq installed and available on PATH?",

Comment: So I have not worked with `yq and jq` so not sure much. But you can try adding all the needed paths in `.bash_profile` and source `.bash_profile` while running the command. That way shell command will know all the paths it needs to refer.

Comment: Or I would suggest you ask one more question specific to this error as people having more experience with `jq and yq` would comment better.